# How do I make the leaderboard section of the code work?

Tags: python

So I'm relatively new to python and I'm having issues with fixing the leaderboard part of the code. I've spent a lot of time but I haven't been able to make it work. I know there are a few examples of answers to the same question on stack overflow but so far none of them have worked. Is there any way to make it work?

```
#task2
import random  #When the user rolls the dice this will give them a random number
import time  #It'll pause the sequence for a specific amount of time
enter = 0  #the number of times a user enters Username and Password
tries = 0  #this is the number of times a user fails to enter the correct verification
rolling = 0  #this is the number of rounds the game continues to loop, which is 5
i = 0 #required for for...loop
rounds = 0 #this is for last while statements where the winner is decided
p1sc = 0 #for total score of player 1 which is added or taken away each round
p2sc = 0 #for total score of player 2 which is added or taken away each round
while enter == 0:  #if enter becomes anything other than 0, the game will start
 try:
  leaderboard_list = [0,0,0,0,0,'-','-','-','-','-']
  file = open('leaderboard.txt', 'x')
  for item in leaderboard_list:
    file.write('%s\n' % item)
  file.close
 except:
  print("")  

  code = input("Input the authorization code to play this game: ")
  if code == ("password"):  #Checking whether the input code is "dice" or not
        print("You have entered authorization code correctly, enjoy the game!")
        player1 = input("What would Player 1 like to be called? ") #asking user 1 to input the name they want to be called
        player2 = input("What would Player 2 like to be called? ") #asking user 2 to input the name they want to be called
        print(player1,"and",player2 +", prepare to play, the game will now start...")
        time.sleep(1)
        enter = 1
  else:
        print("\nIncorrect authorization code please try again!")
        tries = 1 + tries  #required for next if statement
  if tries == 4:  #If user enters wrong password or username 4 times than the user have to wait 1 minute and try again until the user gets username and password correct
        print("You have entered incorrect authorization code too many times, please try again after 1 minute!")
        time.sleep(60)  #For 1 minute the user won't be able to try again
        tries = 0
  else:
        print()
  if enter == 1:
        for i in range(0,5): #this will allow the upcoming code to be looped only 5 times
            while rolling == 0: #if rolling is 1 then player 2 has to roll the dices this continues, until i is in range(0,5)
                p1 = input("\n"+ str(player1) +", press r to roll the dice: ")
                if p1!= "r":
                    print()
                else:
                    p1dice1 = random.randint(1,6)  #allows any number to be chosen from 1 to 6
                    p1dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
                    p1dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
                    print("Rolling dice 1...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("Dice 1 rolled a", p1dice1)
                    print("Rolling dice 2...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("Dice 2 rolled a", p1dice2)
                    p1total = p1dice1 + p1dice2
                    rolling = 1 #for next while loop statement which is for player 2
                    if p1dice1 == p1dice2:  #if statements according to the game rule
                      print("You rolled a double.Well done! You get to roll one more die.")
                      time.sleep(1)
                      print("Rolling dice 3...")
                      time.sleep(1)
                      print("Dice 3 rolled a", p1dice3)
                      p1total = p1total + p1dice3
                    else:
                      p1total = p1total
                    if p1total%2 == 0:  #To check whether the number is odd or even
                        p1sc = p1sc + p1total + 10
                        print("You have total score as an even number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be added by 10. Now,you have",p1sc,"as a total score.")
                    elif p1total%2 == 1:
                        p1sc = p1sc + p1total - 5  #after it is subtracted from 5, elif statement is used as only after subtracting the number; the number can be less than, equal or greater than 0
                        if p1sc == 0:
                            print("You have total score as an odd number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be subtracted 5. Now,you have",p1sc,"as a total score.")
                        elif p1sc < 0:
                            p1sc = 0
                            print("Your total score was subtracted by 5 and went below 0 but according to the game rule, the total score can't go below 0. So, your total score remains 0.")
                        elif p1sc > 0:
                            print("You have total score as an odd number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be subtracted by 5. Now,you have",p1sc,"as a total score.")
                        else:
                            print()
            while rolling == 1: #if rolling is 0 then player 1 has to roll the dices this continues, until i is in range(0,5) 
                p2 = input("\n"+ str(player2) +", press r to roll the dice: ")
                if p2!= "r":
                    print()
                else:
                    p2dice1 = random.randint(1,6)  
                    p2dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
                    p2dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
                    print("Rolling dice 1...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("Dice 1 rolled a", p2dice1)
                    print("Rolling dice 2...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("Dice 2 rolled a", p2dice2)
                    p2total = p2dice1 + p2dice2
                    rolling = 0 #for player 1 to roll the dices again
                    rounds = rounds + 1 #for the game to loop 5 times and be checked by upcoming while rounds == 5
                    if p2dice1 == p2dice2:
                        print("You rolled a double.Well done!You get to roll one more die.")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("Rolling dice 3...")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("Dice 3 rolled a", p2dice3)
                        p2total = p2total + p2dice3
                    else:
                        p2total = p2total
                    if p2total%2 == 0:
                        p2sc = p2sc + p2total + 10
                        print("You have total score as an even number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be added by 10. Now,you have",p2sc,"as a total score.")
                    elif p2total%2 == 1:
                        p2sc = p2sc + p2total - 5 
                        if p2sc == 0:
                            print("You have total score as an odd number. So,according to the rule;your new total score now will be subtracted 5. Now,you have",p2sc,"as a total score.")
                        elif p2sc < 0:
                            p2sc = 0
                            print("Your total score was subtracted by 5 and went below 0 but according to the game rule, the total score can't go below 0. So, your total score remains 0.")
                        elif p2sc > 0:
                            print("You have total score as an odd number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be subtracted by 5. Now,you have",p2sc,"as a total score.")
                        else:
                            print()
            while rounds == 5:
                while p1sc == p2sc:
                    print("\nAs you both have the same score, now you both will have to keep rolling 1 dice until someone wins!")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    p1 = input("\n"+ str(player1) +", press y to roll the dices: ")
                    if p1 != "y":
                        print()
                    else:
                        p1dice1 = random.randint(1,6)  
                        print("Rolling the dice...")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("The dice rolled a", p1dice1)
                        p1total = p1dice1
                        if p1total%2 == 0:  
                            p1sc = p1sc + p1total + 10
                            print("You have total score as an even number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be added by 10.")
                        elif p1total%2 == 1:
                            p1sc = p1sc + p1total - 5  
                            if p1sc == 0:
                                print("You have total score as an odd number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be subtracted 5.")
                            elif p1sc < 0:
                                p1sc = 0
                                print("Your total score was subtracted by 5 :(;(")
                            elif p1sc > 0:
                                print("You have total score as an odd number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be subtracted by 5.")
                            else:
                                print()
                    p2 = input("\n"+ str(player2) +", press y to roll the dices: ")
                    if p2 !="y":
                        print()
                    else:
                       p2dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
                       print("Rolling the dice...")
                       time.sleep(1)
                       print("The dice rolled a", p2dice1)
                       p2total = p2dice1
                       if p2total%2 == 0:
                           p2sc = p2sc + p2total + 10
                           print("You have total score as an even number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be added by 10.")
                       elif p2total%2 == 1:
                           p2sc = p2sc + p2total - 5 
                           if p2sc == 0:
                               print("You have total score as an odd number. So,according to the rule;your new total score now will be subtracted 5.")
                           elif p2sc < 0:
                               p2sc = 0
                               print("Your total score was subtracted by 5 :(;(")
                           elif p2sc > 0:
                               print("You have total score as an odd number. So,according to the game rule;your new total score now will be subtracted by 5.")
                           else:
                               print()                 
                if p1sc > p2sc:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("\nThe scores have been added up and....")
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print(str(player1)+" is the winner with "+str(p1sc)+" points.")
                    print(str(player2)+", better luck next time. Your total score is "+str(p2sc)+".")
                    rounds = 6 #to stop the loop
                else:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("\nThe scores have been added up and....")
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print(str(player2)+" is the winner with "+str(p2sc)+" points.")
                    print(str(player1)+", better luck next time. Your total score is "+str(p1sc)+".")
                    rounds = 6 #to stop the loop

leaderboard_list = [] # Reads the highscore list 
with open('leaderboard.txt') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        leaderboard_list.append(line.rstrip("\r\n"))

for j in range(0,4): #Converts the scores from the list into integers
    leaderboard_list[j] = int(leaderboard_list[j])

for x in range(0,4): #Shuffles the list down depending on how high the scoore was
    curr = leaderboard_list[x]
    if leaderboard >= curr:
        for i in range(5, x + 1, -1):
            leaderboard_list[i + 4] = leaderboard_list[i + 3]
            leaderboard_list[i - 1] = leaderboard_list[i - 2]
        leaderboard_list[x] = leaderboard
        leaderboard_list[(x + 5)] = winner
        break
    else:
        pass

file = open('score.txt', 'w+') #Writes the updated highscore list into the txt file
for item in leaderboard_list:
    file.write('%s\n' % item)
file.close()

print("""The highscores for this game are """) #Prints the highscore list
for x in range(5):
    print(x + 1,") ", leaderboard_list[x], " by ", leaderboard_list[x + 5])
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 190, in <module>
    leaderboard_list[j] = int(leaderboard_list[j])
IndexError: list out of range
```

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: Iterate of the list not over a fixed range with unverified length.

Comment: IndexError: list out of range this error occur because your list is not contains that much element inside try to print this print(len(your_list)) and check your list length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant part of your code is this:

```py
leaderboard_list = [] # Reads the highscore list
with open('leaderboard.txt') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        leaderboard_list.append(line.rstrip("\r\n"))

for j in range(0,4): #Converts the scores from the list into integers
    leaderboard_list[j] = int(leaderboard_list[j])
```

When posting a question here, it's probably best to keep it small like that.

Anyway, you are iterating over range(0,4). This gives you:
[0, 1, 2, 3] as values for j.
So essentially, your for-loop is doing the following:

```py
leaderboard_list[0] = int(leaderboard_list[0])
leaderboard_list[1] = int(leaderboard_list[1])
leaderboard_list[2] = int(leaderboard_list[2])
leaderboard_list[3] = int(leaderboard_list[3])
```

And this crashes with an [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError).
That means that one (or all) of these indexes do not exist. The list is probably either empty, or less than 4 lines long.

The easiest way to debug this is to simply print the list before you do this operation:

```py
print(*leaderboard_list)
```

And the operation that you're trying to do (turn them all into int values) can be done like this:

```py
leaderboard_list = map(int, leaderboard_list)
```

Good luck on your Python journey!